# Ugly edge with rounded rectangle geometry on layer

Tags: c++, direct2d

I have some rounded rectangle geometry.

```
ID2D1RoundedRectangleGeometry *geo; (1)
```

First I draw it

```
target->FillGeometry(geo, brush); (2)
```

Then I apply clipping mask using `ID2D1Layer` with the same geometry:

```
target->PushLayer(D2D1::LayerParameters(D2D1::InfiniteRect(), geo), nullptr); (3)
```

And then, with layer I make some draw over it:

```
target->FillGeometry(mask, anotherBrush); (4)
... another draw calls
```

The result:

[image]

As you can see there is a problem with edges, seems like some part of initial draw (1) is not covered by mask, although has the same geometry.

Can it be solved without resizing initial draw area or the layer area?

---

Specifying antialias mode at (3), changes the result a bit, but still unsatisfying:

```
 target->PushLayer(D2D1::LayerParameters(D2D1::InfiniteRect(), geo, D2D1_ANTIALIAS_MODE_ALIASED), nullptr); (3)
```

[image]

Comment: What is the antialias mode of the renter target? ID2D1RenderTarget::GetAntialiasMode

Comment: @SimonMourier, well I do not specify antialias mode for render target, so it should to be default. Also there are few render targets: "main" `ID2D1HwndRenderTarget`, created by it `ID2D1BitmapRenderTarget` and `QueryInterface` from it `ID2D1DeviceContext`. The code in my post draws to last one target, and then it copied to hwnd target

Comment: @SimonMourier, I checked, all render targets have `D2D1_ANTIALIAS_MODE_PER_PRIMITIVE` mode

Comment: D2D1_ANTIALIAS_MODE_PER_PRIMITIVE means aliased, it's probably the cause.

Comment: @SimonMourier, You mean `D2D1_ANTIALIAS_MODE_ALIASED` should be set then? There are only three elements in the `D2D1_ANTIALIAS_MODE` enumeration, and word stuff is the third.

Comment: @SimonMourier I tried both, however, for all render targets I have and that edges are still there. I currently made a solution by make (1) draw with `right - 1`, `left + 1`, but it makes another visual problems, although edges problem is (almost) solved with that approach